# How do I jump to the start or the end of an OCaml block in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ocaml

Sometimes I look at code that goes like this:

```ml
let x =   
  (* 1 million lines of code *)
  let y =
     (* 5 billion lines of code *)
  in
  (* 5 lines of code *)
in
```

and I find myself scrolling with my cursor on the right indentation to find where a `let ... in` starts or ends. Is there a better way to do this in VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure if such a feature exists in VSCode but you can try this extension which I recommend [Block Travel](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sashaweiss.block-travel) it doesn't jump to the start or the end of a block code it seems to be so hard to understand when a block begins and ends but it lets you jump up or down to the nearest all white line.

by default the shortcuts are :

```
alt+up
alt+shift+up
alt+down
alt+shift+down
```

but you can update them.

Comment: unfortunately the code I'm looking at has barely any whitelines

Answer (score 0):

I have a treat for you: [the Navi Parens extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lukstafi.navi-parens). It is language-agnostic (but has support for OCaml comment and array delimiters in the "Raw brackets" mode).